# My app has unfortunately stopped

Tags: java, android

This is my code

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            try {
                if (myswitch.isChecked()) {
                    editText.setHint("IDR");
                    editText1.setHint("USD");
                    double Rupiah = Double.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());


                    double convusd = Rupiah / 13698;

                    DecimalFormat dformat = new DecimalFormat("####,###,###.00");


                    editText1.setText(String.format("$" + dformat.format(convusd)));
                } else {
                    editText.setHint("USD");
                    editText1.setHint("IDR");
                    double USD = Double.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());


                    double convidr = USD * 13698;
                    DecimalFormat dformat = new DecimalFormat("####,###,###.00");


                    editText1.setText(String.valueOf("Rp." + dformat.format(convidr)));
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    });`
```

My app has an error if the EditText is empty when I press the Button.

Comment: Unfortunately, you've not provided enough context and your question is too broad.  What does the code above do?  What is the exception that you are receiving?  Please specify what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few problems:

1. Why are you setting hints after the click and in the same event you try to convert to values? shouldn't the user first see the hint, enter the values and only then you convert the input?
2. When you attempt to convert the input, you should check if there is actually a value inside, e.g:

   ```
   String inputVal = editText.getText();     

   if(inputVal != null && !inputVal.isEmpty())
   {
      //do some stuff
   }
   ```
3. If there is a value, make sure it what you expect it to be.
   Set your input type to your EditText:

   ```
   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
   ```

   and to be extra sure you should do somthing like this:

   ```
   double d;
   try {
        d = Double.parseDouble(inputVal);
       }
   catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     // The input is not what you thought it was, handle it
   }
   ```

Comment: i have to try this but still get error, i alredy put this code                              `String a=editText.getText().toString();
           if(a!=null&&!a.isEmpty())
           {
               editText.setText("");
           }`

Comment: but when the value is null is getting error.and then when i input a value in my textbox your code is working. i'm very confuse please help me :)

Comment: Do something like this:

String a = editText.getText().toString();
if (a.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
   //there is input you can do what you need
}

Comment: Thanks,.. this is totally working  :)

Answer (score 0):

Change code as like below

```
       String a=editText.getText().toString();     
       if(a!=null&&!a.isEmpty())
         {
                double Rupiah = Double.valueOf(a);
         }
```

Comment: i alredy try this , but still error . thanks before :)

Answer (score 0):

Add empty check When you click the button. you might be trying to convert empty string to double

```
if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty){
double Rupiah = Double.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
...
}
```

Comment: let me know if it helps.

Comment: this is not working for me but thanks before :)

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
       @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            try { 
                if (myswitch.isChecked()) { 
                    editText.setHint("IDR"); 
                    editText1.setHint("USD"); 
                    double Rupiah = Double.valueOf(editText.getText() ==null ? "":editText.getText().toString());


                    double convusd = Rupiah / 13698;

                    DecimalFormat dformat = new DecimalFormat("####,###,###.00");


                    editText1.setText(String.format("$" + dformat.format(convusd)));
                } else { 
                    editText.setHint("USD"); 
                    editText1.setHint("IDR"); 
                    double USD = Double.valueOf(editText.getText() ==null ? "":editText.getText().toString());


                    double convidr = USD * 13698;
                    DecimalFormat dformat = new DecimalFormat("####,###,###.00");


                    editText1.setText(String.valueOf("Rp." + dformat.format(convidr)));
                } 


            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            } 
        } 

    });`
```